# jQuery-ui breaks animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a div that has some animation in it, and when I add in the jquery-ui, the animation event does not fire.  If I comment out the lines that enable jQuery-UI, everything works fine (except the ui functions of course).  Here is a snippet of the code I'm having issues with.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content").children().hide();
    $("#Home").show();

    $("#pagenav ul li").click(function() {
    $("nav ul li").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $("#content").children().hide();
    $("#" + $(this).data("name")).show();
    });
    $("#myImageBox ul li").hide(function() {
    $("#myImageBox ul li").each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(1000*index).fadeIn(500);
    });
    });
    $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3" });
    });
 </script>
```

Any idea as to why this would cause issues?  Thanks for any advice.

Edit: here is the code I'm using to call the scripts/css etc.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/south-street/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css">
```

Comment: The first parts of the code are working by the way, it is hiding the parts that need hidden, but it isn't running the animation.  It is also adding the accordion element to the specified element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't looked too closely, but problems can be caused by loading CSS after the JS.

Try changing the load order so that the css is call first, and load the jQuery.UI Css before your stylesheet, so your stylesheet can make the modifications needed.

Comment: Also - this line looks wrong:                                          `$(this).delay(1000*index).fadeIn(500);`

Comment: Tried making the changes you suggested, and no luck.  Also if the line looks wrong, what would you suggest I do to fix it?  Thanks for you help though :)

Comment: Sorry I was looking through the wrong end of the telescope - that line looks fine.

Comment: I did some tests and I had problems with code not firing when it was inside the $.hide function callback - I don't know why this is, but I am betting that is where your problem is - you might try using $.fadeOut instead of $.hide - or rearranging the way it is called.

Comment: When I try your code on a list - it takes a really long time to fadeIn - I think this is related to using $(selector).each() inside the hide function